# VS2010 Classic ASP support

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, asp-classic

With Visual Studio 2005, 2008, and 2010 you can debug Classic ASP by attaching the debugger to the w3wp.exe process. This is very buggy and crashes often in 2005 and 2008, but works well in 2010. The only problem is that, as far as I can tell, VS2010 does not support Classic ASP code highlighting or code completion. HTML looks fine, but any Classic ASP code is just plain black-on-white.

I can't add `<%@Script="VBScript"%>` to the top of each page because of the site architecture, and even after testing that - it doesn't do anything.

This whole issue is highly confusing because with **Visual Studio 2010 Express**, the aforementioned Classic ASP support comes out of the box (minus debugging).

I can get alternating HTML and VBScript highlighting by switching between the following modes (but never both). I have tried the following: Tools > Options > Text Editor > File Extensions > Adding an "ASP" extension with the following Editors:

- Automatic Editor Selector (XML) - gets the HTML right, but no dice on
  the ASP
- Microsoft Visual Basic - gets the ASP mostly right (lots of
  underlined errors even though code is up to ASP standard), but no
  HTML highlighting
- Script Editor - HTML but no ASP
- Web Form Editor - HTML but no ASP

I have considered [extending the Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885242.aspx), my thoughts being to try and mix the markup for the Web Form Editor and the Microsoft Visual Basic editor, but am unsure if this is a reasonable course of action.

How can I get code highlighting and intellisense for Classic ASP in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: ASP Intellisense works fine for me out of the box with VS2010 Professional ([screenshot](http://i19.photobucket.com/albums/b173/gfngfgf/vs2010-classicasp.png)).  Which version of VS2010 do you have?  Do you have Visual Web Developer installed?

Comment: Fascinating! Your code highlighting also seems to be working ... just a different colour set. I'm using a trial of VS2010 Ultimate. I have VWD installed as well. I'll give Professional a try. Why do you ask about VWD?

Comment: I thought maybe Classic ASP Intellisense wouldn't work if VWD wasn't installed.  (By the way, I'm talking about the component of the full Visual Studio, not VWD Express.  You can check if it's installed by selecting "Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio")

Comment: OK, yes I checked and it is installed. I misunderstood you there.

Comment: Hm ... uninstalled everything related to Visual Studio and installed 2008. Same problem. I'm using version 10.0.30319.1 RMTRel. There must be something I'm missing. Are you creating a special type of project?

Comment: Honestly your screenshot is haunting me! I can't believe it works for you out of the box. Any one else have experience with this?

Comment: OK I installed it on a totally different computer and have not had problems. Only difference during install is that it downloaded + installed Service Pack 1. Going to try that on my dev machine. Otherwise, it's obviously some registry/other program that's messing it up. I'll post my solution with more details when I'm done. Thank you for the screenshot, it gave me hope :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

**TL;dr:** Install Service Pack 1

Walk you through the troubleshooting process:

- Uninstalled VS2010 Ultimate completely on machine with problems
- Installed VS2010 Professional as per comments. This did not solve the
  issue. Same problems as before.
- On a new computer with a fresh install of Windows 7 I installed VS2010 Professional.
- This time it asked me to install Service Pack 1 after installing
  (http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=23691).
- Went into the asp code and it was highlighting and code suggesting
  perfectly. Debugging worked flawlessly as well.
- Returned to original (faulty) computer and manually installed SP1 and the problem went
  away.

Comment: ASP syntax highlighting worked for me before SP1, but I'm glad you got your problem figured out!